# Flutter GetX Get.find() returning null in one class, but finding it in another?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I have multiple controllers for my Webpage using GetX. The `authController` logs the user in and calls the database api to fetch the user from firebase firestore:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
btnController.value.success();
UserCredential _authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.trim(), password: password);
Get.find<UserController>().user = await Database().getUser(_authResult.user!.uid);
```

The `userController` is a very simple controller:

```
class UserController extends GetxController {
  Rx<UserModel> _userModel = UserModel().obs;

  UserModel get user => _userModel.value;

  set user(UserModel value) => this._userModel.value = value;

  void clear() {
    _userModel.value = UserModel();
  }
}
```

The `UserModel` itself has a constructor like this, with all the fields being indicated with `?` (null-safety)

```
UserModel.createUser({required final data}) {
    role = data["User_Role"];
    firstName = data["firstName"];
    lastName = data["lastName"];
    age = data["age"];
    privateAdress = Adress.fromLinkedMap(data: data["privateAdress"]);
    dateOfBirth = data["dateOfBirth"].toDate();
    driverCardNumber = data["driverCardNumber"];
    driverLicenseNumber = data["driverLicenseNumber"];
    email = data["email"];
    id = data["employee_ID"];
    lastLoginTime = data["lastLoginTime"];
    mobilePhoneNumber = data["mobilePhoneNumber"];
    photo = data["photo"];
  }
```

Here is the Problem:

When I try to access the User using Get.find().user in the `AuthClass`, I am able to get it. However, as soon as I try to access it anywhere else, I only get null as a result. I am also calling these methods right at the start of the webapp and all the other controllers work just fine:

```
Get.put(AuthController());
Get.put(UserController());
Get.put(DashboardController());
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! I was not able to get the `UserController` data due to the binding of the `FirebaseAuth`. That's because I called `firebaseUser.bindStream(auth.authStateChanges())` and my Login Screen was listening to that value, hence opening the dashboard **before** the user was pulled:

```
UserCredential _authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.trim(),
        password: password,
      ); // The dashboard was already opened here
Get.find<UserController>().user =
      await Database().getUser(_authResult.user!.uid);
```

I simply added a bool `final loggedIn = false.obs` to my auth Class and set that to true **after** the user has been created.